# Why do I get only 80% points in this question?

Tags: soft-question

I solved this question below in a public contest and I don't know why one of the examiners gave me 12/15 points.

> **Question:** If $a<b\in\mathbb R$ and $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ a real function, continuous in $[a,b]$ and derivable in $(a,b)$. Show if
>   $f'(x)=0$, for every $x\in (a,b)$, then there is $k\in \mathbb R$,
>   such that $f(x)=k$, for every $x\in [a,b]$.
>
> **Solution:** Let $h>0$ such that $a+h<b$. Applying the Mean Value Theorem in $[a+h,b]$, there is a $c\in(a+h,b)$ such that
>
> $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a+h)}{b-a-h}=0$$
>
> It follows $f(a+h)=f(b)$ which also follows $f$ is constant $f(x)=k$
>   with $k=f(b)$.

The only mistake I found was forgetting to prove $f(a)=k$, are there other mistakes? I don't understand why I got only 80% of this question.

Comment: I couldn't say why a grader did this, but it is better to just say $x\in (a,b)$ rather than writing your arbitrary point as $a+h$. variable, which is confusing. But yes, skipping $h=0$ is a likely cause for the lost points.

Comment: Yeah you should have just taken $\lim_{h \to 0^+}$ and then I think you'd have gotten full points for sure.

Comment: I might agree.  You need to get $f(a)=k$ as well since your argument assumed $h >0$.  This is a continuity argument, and is likely worth 20% of the problem.

Comment: Question has too many $x$s in it

Comment: You mean too many commas?